# Double Align in Side to Side equations

Tags: align, alignment, horizontal

I want to align two equations side to side. In alignment, I can use `$a=b && c=d$` to do that. However, I can only align with one equal sign with that method. That is,

```
\begin{align*}
    189410 &= 13\cdot13753+10621 && a = b\\
    a &= x && a12312 = b
\end{align*}
```

This code here outputs this (the second equal sign is not aligned):

[image]

and this code outputs this (weird space):

```
\begin{align*}
    189410 &= 13\cdot13753+10621 && a &= b\\
    a &= x && a12312 &=b
\end{align*}
```

[image]

How can I fix it? (Preferably not using multicol but it's fine if there are no other solutions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one too many `&` in the separation of your equations.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  189410 &= 13 \cdot 13753 + 10621 &      a &= b \\
       a &= x                      & a12312 &= b
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I use `boxed` in align?

Comment: @CELLSecret: Load `mathtools` in the place of `amsmath`, and use the `\Aboxed` command: it  can contain an ampersand.

Comment: @CELLSecret -- Depends on how you want to use `boxed`.  If it's within a single cell, it should be okay, but if you want to do something that would put an `&` inside, I predict an error message.  This is a different question.  Please ask one, and be specific about what tou want.

Comment: I did put an `&` inside but there were no error message. It's just that the equations are no longer aligned... but I think I got it sorted now. thanks